# Phone Directory program for loop in switch case

Tags: c++

I am making a C++ Telephone Directory program, but I am facing some troubles.
The code I am posting may have some mistakes as it is not completed yet, you may notice alot of program code is in comments, it's in Phase-1.

Anyhow, my main question is how can I use for loop inside switch case. What I want to do is: As the object Telephone Directory is an array we will need to use for loop,so when the user selects option 1, it will go into the for loop and do he work on 0 index and comes right out of for loop, and if the user selects option 1 again later sometime, I don't want the index to start from 0,but start from 1 (or whatever index it should be on)

I see two solutions:

(1) Use for loop in switch cases
(2) Use for loop in a member function

But I have tried both ways and it's not working.
For loop either completes it's whole loop (if I add "break;" word, it starts from 0 index again).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    public:
    //already private
    /*string first_name;
    string last_name;*/
    string Name;
    string ID;
    string Address;
    string Phone_Number;
    float CGPA;

    public:
        Student()
        {
            Name=" ";
            ID=" ";
            Address=" ";
            Phone_Number=" ";
            CGPA=0.0;
        }

        void student_data_input()
        {
            cout<<"Enter ID: "<<endl;
            cin>>ID;
            cout<<"Enter name: "<<endl;
            cin>>Name;
            cout<<"Enter Address: "<<endl;
            cin>>Address;
            cout<<"Enter Phone Number: "<<endl;
            cin>>Phone_Number;
            cout<<"Enter CGPA: "<<endl;
            cin>>CGPA;
        }
        void student_data_display()
        {
            cout<<"ID: "<<ID<<endl;
            cout<<"Name: "<<Name<<endl;
            cout<<"Address: "<<Address<<endl;
            cout<<"Phone Number: "<<Phone_Number<<endl;
            cout<<"CGPA: "<<CGPA<<endl;
        }
        void student_data_delete()
        {
            Name=" ";
            ID=" ";
            Address=" ";
            Phone_Number=" ";
            CGPA=0.0;
        }
        /*void student_data_search(string s_n, int a, Student obj_1[] )
        {
            cout<<"YES";
            
            for(int i=0 ; i<=2 ; i++)
            {
                if(s_n==obj_1[i].ID)
                cout<<"Found it";
            }
            cout<<"Hey;";*/
        }
        
        
};

/*void Student::student_data_search(string s_n, int a, Student obj_1[] )
{
    cout<<"abd";
}*/




int main()
{
    cout << "***************************" << endl;
    cout << "\n    Telephone Directory\n" << endl;
    cout << "***************************" << endl;

    cout<<"Please enter how many Student's record you want to save: "<<endl;
    int records;
    cin>>records;
    Student Telephone_directory[records];
    int counts, i;
    int option;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n             Telephone Directory: Main Menu\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Insert a New Student"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Update and existing Student"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Delete a record"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Search for a student (using name or ID)"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. List directory"<<endl;
        cout<<"[Select option from 1 to 5]"<<endl;
        
        cin>>option;
        
        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Insert Menu"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                for (i=0 ; i<=record-1 ; i++)
                {
                    Telephone_directory[i].students_data_input();
                }
                
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Update Menu"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Delete Menu"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Search Menu"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Directory Members"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid option"<<endl;
            
            
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
    



    return 0;
}
```

b

Comment: When you are inserting a new record, you don't have to loop over the whole array, you only need get the inputs for a single `Student` at the end of the list.  In other words, you need to keep track of the current number of students in the directory, which is different from the maximum size of the directory.

Comment: Also, `Student Telephone_directory[records];` is a non-standard compiler extension - the array size must be known at compile time.  If you need a variable-length array, you probably want to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I haven't read std::vector yet. Also, you are saying I shouldn't use for loop?

Comment: You'll need loops for options like #4 and #5.  But for #1 you don't need to loop over anything because you are only inserting a single record.

Comment: "_you may notice alot of program code is in comments, it's in Phase-1_" - You're supposed to make a [mcve] to make it easy to focus on the problem at hand. Remove everything not needed to demonstrate the problem you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You so much, I solved it by this method.

```
 case 1:
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Insert Menu"<<endl;
                cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
                while(i<records)
                {
                    Telephone_directory[i].Phone_Directory_data_input();
                    cout<<"Press 1 to save and 0 not to save"<<endl;
                    cin>>choice;
                    if(choice==0) 
                    {
                        Telephone_directory[i].Phone_Directory_data_delete();
                        cout<<"Data deleted"<<endl;
                    }
                    else if (choice==1)
                    {
                        cout<<"Data saved successfully"<<endl;
                        i++;
                    }

                    cout<<"Want to insert another record? [y/n]"<<endl;
                    cin>>choice_y_n;
                    if(choice_y_n=='y')
                    {
                        cout<<"Redirecting to Insert Menu again"<<endl;
                    }
                    else if (choice_y_n=='n')
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

## Functions good.  Copy/paste coding bad.

Drawn out explanation:

I strongly recommend your switch simply call a different member function, and that you move as much redundant code (also called "boiler plate") into its own function[s] as much as possible.

For example:

```
    case 2:
        cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Update Menu"<<endl;
        cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"             Telephone Directory: Delete Menu"<<endl;
        cout<<"******************************************************"<<endl;
        break;
```

could become something like

```
void printHeaderBar()
{
    cout << "******************************************************" << endl;
}

void printHeader(const char *menuName)
{
    printHeaderBar();
    cout << "             Telephone Directory: " << menuName << endl;
    printHeaderBar();
}

...
    case 2:
        printHeader("Update Menu");
        printUpdateMenu();
        break;
    case 3:
        printHeader("Delete Menu");
        printDeleteMenu();
        break;
```

One could argue against `printStars` in particular as it is really just a single line function, and I could honestly go either way on that one.  But `printHeader` should be a no-brainer.  You might even move the calls to printHeader within each individual `printFooMenu` function.

In this instance, it may not seem like that big of a deal, but let me pose a hypothetical situation for you:

You're writing some application, and have 6 copies of a given piece of code, similar to what I'm asking you to consolidate into `printHeader`.  Somebody finds a bug that is traced back to an instance of that copied code.  Depending on how experienced/wise the programmer working on that bug is, there are several possible responses.

1. A noob programmer, wet behind the ears, working on their first bug:  They fix that instance, and call it fixed.  They are then shocked when, months later, "that same bug" crops up somewhere else.
2. A programmer with some experience fixes that instance, searches for similar code and fixes *some-but-not-all* of the code.  Months later, "that same bug" crops up somewhere else.
3. A programmer with a bit more experience will successfully find all the instances and fix them.
4. A genuinely skilled programmer will create a function with all the duplicate code consolidated into one place, and then call that code from all the places where the copied code once lived.  ANY FUTURE BUG FIXES on this area of the code need only be dealt with once.

Many small functions are easy to test and debug.  One great big mess is going to stay a mess and be hard to understand.

Comment: Thank You so much. It is a very easy method and I didn't even though of doing that. Going to implement this in my future codes.